# get the selected text from the rich text box

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to get the selected text from the rich text box , but i am not getting how to do it. if user selects a particular text from the rich text box by pressing some key that selected text should store in a string variable (or) display as message .

Comment: what do you mean particular text.. 1 word or 1 letter? mean highlighted text?

Comment: if there is any paragraph ,.. then user will select any part of that with using mouse then later if a specified key is pressed from the keyboard then that that part of text that user selected should display in the message box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`SelectedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx)** property

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText
```

Comment: you can use it anywhere you want. inside a button or selectedchange

Comment: If i use that , its giving an red underline for SelectedText and say it doesnot contain definition

Comment: yes , it says rich text box doesnt contain definition for selectedText.   
   private void form1_keyDown(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1 )
            {        
                MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.SelectedText);           
            } }

Answer (score 1):

This one highlight the text first then press on keyboard

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
 }
```

Comment: it displays that selectedtext does not contain definition.